# MacにPHPをインストール出来ない。

Tags: php, macos

Mac Yosemiteにanyenvを使ってPHP5.6.8をインストールしようとしたのですが、以下のエラーが出てしまいできません。

**エラー**

```html
-----------------
|  BUILD ERROR  |
-----------------

Here are the last 10 lines from the log:

-----------------------------------------
                       ^
/usr/include/math.h:718:12: note: 'finite' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
extern int finite(double) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_0, __MAC_10_9, __IPHONE_NA, __IPHONE_NA);
           ^
1 warning generated.
/var/tmp/php-build/source/5.6.8/Zend/zend_string.c:65:28: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
        CG(interned_empty_string) = zend_new_interned_string_int("", sizeof(""), 0 TSRMLS_CC);
                                  ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
PEAR package PHP_Archive not installed: generated phar will require PHP's phar extension be enabled.
-----------------------------------------

The full Log is available at '/tmp/php-build.5.6.8.20150513233015.log'.
[Warn]: Aborting build.
```

このエラーについて調べて見ると以下のサイトに書かれていました。
http://qiita.com/omega999/items/c5b1c177331f8d342efd

しかしこのサイトに書かれている内容は少し古いようで、現在ではこのサイトに書かれている`xdebug.sh`は以下のリンクのように書き換えられていました。
https://github.com/php-build/php-build/blob/master/share/php-build/plugins.d/xdebug.sh

この変更後の解決方法について調べてみたのですが、みつけられませんでした。どなたかこの状態での解決方法がわかる方、その方法、あるいは参考になるサイトを教えてください。よろしくおねがいします。

**追記1**

このcommitで変更されているようです。
https://github.com/php-build/php-build/commit/ad455b9e6e6c08e7ed86c37c1649af600256ac06

Answer (score 1):

macとの交換性の問題に見えますね。エラーの内容も'finite'がmacの10.0、10.9では利用できないとのエラーなのでphpのバージョンをあげることをお勧めします。

自分は基本macだとMacPortsを利用して環境構築を行なっているので、その方法をお勧めします。

あんまり役に立たずごめんなさい。